# Use Socket.IO to update data in real-time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am writing a nodejs / express / mongodb based web application and all is working great.

What I've made for learning purposes is a twitter clone.

People can tweet whatever they want and it will show up on their profile and anyone who follows them stream.

On my home page it shows everyone who you are followings posts.

I want this stream to automatically update when someone they are following posts something new.

So they can just sit their on the home page and see all new posts come in in real time.

I've worked with Socket.IO in the past and loved it for it's awesome simplicity of use.

But is Socket.IO an appropriate use for this sort of situation?

Are their better options I can use, perhaps going with a simpler approach of AJAX polling would be more efficient for scalability?

So basically what is the best to use for an application like this?
I need:

- Realtime updates to the client
- Scalability and effeciency

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple option 
My firstoption RacerJS
and Socket.IO

Get data from mongodb and send through racerjs or socket.io

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am now taking a look at Racer!

Answer (score 1):

**RacerJS** is synchronization model built on top of ShareJS, which has underlying technique called Operational Transformation, this is used to do collaborative work on the same data in real-time (like Google docs) I guess it does not really apply to your case or its not the case where it should be used. Because ShareJS does a lot of work to keep clients able to edit at the same time on the same data. This is not the case with Activity streams like your case.

A good option would be [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)